# Whether to use gerund or infinitive with word 'hesitate'?

Tags: gerunds, gerund-vs-infinitive

Firstly, i am giving some sentences from some books and links:

1. She **hesitates** singing in the company of her friends.
   (from my local book)
2. In order to oblige others or amuse herself, she never **hesitated** sacrificing her own interests to the idea of doing what pleased her.
   (from https://www.google.co.in/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=she+never+hesitated+sacrificing) - look for 'The New York Mirror'
3. I hesitate to try the experiment again.
   (from http://www.writing.utoronto.ca/advice/english-as-a-second-language/gerunds) - search for 'hesitate'
4. She never hesitates to sacrifice her time and energy for the people of her house.
   (from SAME LINK IN SENTENCE 2) -  look for 'Shadows of My Memories - Page 184'

In my local book, it is written that if there is a sense of dislike, hesitation, risk etc. in a sentence, use gerund. e.g., sentence 1.

Then, after reading further, it is written that verbs such as remember,.........., hesitate,......., etc. are followed by infinitive.

Searching on internet, i get contradicting sentence w.r.t. grammar as i mentioned above examples. So, please clarify whether to use gerund or infinitive with 'hesitate'.

Comment: Please always use uppercase for the first person pronoun "I". It is an error to write it as "i".

Comment: *hesitates to sing* is much more natural to me than *hesitates singing*.

Comment: I would say that _hesitates singing_ is ungrammatical. I've never encountered _hesitate_ with a gerund, and certainly the rule you state is incorrect. Better get a better book.

Comment: I normally *hesitate saying* anything is "ungrammatical", but in this case I'm with @John.

Comment: First of all the New York Mirror ceased publication in 1842, so I would consider that a pretty archaic source for grammatical usage. I rarely hear the gerund used. (I live in the Midwest US) The infinitive sounds more correct.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I also want to know is my title 'whether to use .......?' correct w.r.t. grammar?